# Place label on top of each other next to an image

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode9

I'm trying to place a label on top of label next to my image.

[image]

I have tried

[image]

I had

[image]

I want these number to display here

[image]

Should I look into a stack or some short?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I might be tempted to just use a `UIStackView` - it might be a little overkill, but one of the benefits is if you hide one of the labels (because it's text is nil) it will reduce the size of the `StackView`, which, personally, makes the layout look nicer, but that's me

## General layout...

[image: General layout]

## `UIImageView` constraints

[image: UIImageView constraints]

## `UIStackView` constraints

[image: StackView constraints]

## `UIStackView` properties

[image: UIStackView properties]

*nb: This still assumes that the overall height of the text won't exceed the height of the `UIImageView`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement, I created it in storyboard; u can do same like it to achieve your prototype :

- Constraints for label 2 (Devices):

[image]

- Constraints for Label 1 (John) :

[image]

I hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: what is your result look like ?

Comment: It will look like your prototype. Let me know if your's not looking exactly samilar to that.

Comment: I might consider using a `StackView` to contain the labels, which can then be aligned to the vertical centre of the image view